# Inputting and Formatting Strings

Tags: python, string, variables, input, format

I am writing a menu for a game in Python but am coming across a problem when trying to ask the user for their name.

```
user_name = str(input("\033[4;32mPlease Enter Your Name:"))
print("Hello {0}".format(user_name))
```

When ran, the program will only display the .format(user_name) if a number is inputted but when a string is inputted it comes up with an error saying that the string is not defined.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In python3, you could do like this:

```
user_name = str(input("\033[4;32mPlease Enter Your Name:" + "\033[0m"))
print(f"Hello {user_name}")
```

In python2, you should probably remove the zero from inside the brackets: (your code works as is with python 3.6)

```
user_name = str(input("\033[4;32mPlease Enter Your Name:" + "\033[0m"))
print("Hello {}".format(user_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the zero from the formatting:

```
user_name = str(input("\033[4;32mPlease Enter Your Name:"))
print("Hello {}".format(user_name))
```